# How to loop through CheckBoxes on UserForm?

Tags: excel, vba

By selecting an OptionButton I want all CheckBoxes on the active form to deselect AND UNCHECK.

I can get it to deselect using the For Each Loop but this does not work for unchecking the boxes. I get the error:

> chB.Value=Object variable or With block variable not set

```
Private Sub optB_9201_Click()

Dim ctrl As Control
Dim chB As CheckBox

If Me.optB_9201.Value = True _
  And Me.optB_9251.Value = False _
  And Me.optB_9301.Value = False Then

    Me.img9301_main.Visible = True
    Me.frM9301_View.Caption = "Du har valgt CLX-9201NA med følgende konfigurasjon:"
    Me.frm9301_Equipment.Enabled = True

    For Each ctrl In Me.frm9301_Equipment.Controls
        ctrl.Enabled = False
        chB.Value = False
    Next ctrl

    Me.frM9301_Stand.Enabled = True

    For Each ctrl In Me.frM9301_Stand.Controls
        ctrl.Enabled = True
    Next ctrl

End If

End Sub
```

How to fix this?

Alternatively:

Is is possible to have a change event on the UserForm that states that if a CheckBox is Enabled= False Then Value=False.

This way I would not have to put in the For Each Loop on every OptionButton. I tried the UserForm_Change Sub and UserForm_Click but nothing seems to work.

Comment: David's answer below solves your issue. Also,  in your initial `if` statement you don't need to test for `True` and `False` explicitly. Instead use: `If Me.optB_9201 And Not Me.optB_9251 And Not Me.optB_9301 Then`.

Comment: I wrote a post about [checkboxes working together](http://yoursumbuddy.com/userform-event-handler-class-multiple-controls/) which might be of interest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You never Assign anything to `chb` (and I'm not sure that you need to use that variable at all). You could do:

```
For Each ctrl In Me.frm9301_Equipment.Controls
    ctrl.Enabled = False
    ctrl.Value = False
Next ctrl
```

This will only work if **all** controls are CheckBoxes. If that is not the case, then just add some if/then logic:

```
For Each ctrl In Me.frm9301_Equipment.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
        ctrl.Enabled = False
        ctrl.Value = False
    End If
Next ctrl
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks David:) I tried your first option before I posted but that did not work for me even though all controls are CheckBoxes. But your second option using the TypeName solved it!!

Comment: If the first option didn't work, then the form contains some controls which *aren't* checkboxes (textboxes, comboboxes, option buttons, listboxes, etc., -- even *labels* are controls on a userform).  Glad it worked for you !

Comment: This is a big help, thanks. Make sure to note that the line `If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox"` is case sensitive!

Comment: @PGCodeRider string comparisons are always case sensitive *unless* you use `Option Compare Text`.

Comment: @DavidZemens yes I know, I was just trying to make it easier for less experienced coders. People only know what they know, so the comment in code was just a short tip. For me the value was in the ‘TypeName’ procedure, as I was unfamiliar with that.

Comment: @PGCodeRider I understand sure, and you're not wrong per se but we can't use every answer as an opportunity to hand-hold every potential problem a novice dev might encounter -- almost, if not every language treats strings distinctly by case. failing to account for this is almost surely among the first lessons that every dev learns, even if self-taught. It's why VBA has an LCASE and UCASE function, why python has a lower() and upper() method, why C# has a ToLower(), etc. :)

Comment: @DavidZemens you’re right about the language consistency, but I would argue that most VBA coders don’t have such a background, and instead come from the excel world where Boolean statements are insensitive (unless leveraging the ‘Exact’ function). Anyway, your point in self taught people will indeed figure it out quickly is indeed correct. Not a big deal to me. Thanks for the thoughtful banter.