# How to use On Error to break a loop in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I'm currently making a form that contains a single multi page with 11 pages. Each page has multiple check boxes, ranging from 3 - 12 check boxes. The check boxes represent list items going like follows:

I plan to use a 2 dimensional for loop (for loop within for loop) to check each box using the following syntax.

I'm used to Python, so my thinking was loop until an error occurs (Indicating no more check boxes) and then break the current loop and continue.

```
For Each pg In Me.MultiPage1.Pages
    x = 1
    For i = 0 To 12 
        If ActiveSheet.Shapes("CheckBox" & x & i).Value = xlOn Then
            'Code to be executed
             x = x = 1
    On Error ExitHandler

ExitHandler:
    Exit
```

So I'm trying to do something similar to the functionality of ***continue*** within Python. Or perhaps I am going about this in a completely incorrect manner.

Furthermore, I am also unsure if my method of naming the check boxes is correct as they are related to list items that goes as follows:

```
1.1
1.2
1.3
...

11.1
11.2
11.3
```

I'm also just realising the naming for the check boxes may be a bit messed up. I used the following method. It goes:

```
Page 1
CheckBox11
CheckBox12
CheckBox13 
CheckBox14

Page 2
CheckBox21,
CheckBox22, 
CheckBox23, 
CheckBox24,

...
Page 11
CheckBoxEleven1,
CheckBoxEleven2, 
CheckBoxEleven3, 
CheckBoxEleven4, 
CheckBoxEleven5,
```

I used "Eleven" because the check box names for 1.11 and 1.12 were conflicting and causing an Ambiguous Name error.

Comment: This [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24221408/7558682) might be a better idea, loop trhough all the checkboxes for each multipage.

Comment: What you're describing fits a `break` statement in python not `continue`. The equivalent in VBA is `Exit For`. This will leave the inner for loop and continue to the next iteration in the outer loop. You could also name your check boxes "ChecBox1_1", "CheckBox11_1" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the replies, they have given me a better understanding of the error handling system of VBA.

I have created the solution to my issue using a similar approach to what was pointed out by @Damian in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221346/how-to-loop-through-checkboxes-on-userform/24221408#24221408).

```
Dim cont As Control

For Each pg In Me.MultiPage1.Pages
        
    For Each cont In pg.Controls
            
        If cont.Value = True Then
            checkBoxes.Add cont.Caption
        End If

            
    Next cont

Next pg
```

Just needed to place the controls of the page into a variable Control variable which I could use with a For Each to loop the exact amount of times I need to be able to check the check box. This solution works for me as I only have checkbox controls on the page. Therefore, all I needed to do is check the value of the control, instead of also checking the type of control.

If I had other controls then I would need to check the type of control first. This also means I don't have to formulate the name of the checkbox as I was attempting before.

Answer (score 1):

To your first problem: Move the 'On Error GoTo ExitHandler' above the line that can cause the error. Excel needs to know what to do in case of an error before it happens.

Answer (score 1):

Basic logic for Errorhandler in VBA is something like this:

```
Sub Something()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'Your loop here

    Exit Sub 'Exit sub if no error appears
    
ErrorHandler:
        ' If error do something else
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exit the loop when an error occurs, this can be done using `On Error GoTo ExitHandler`. As stated by *stephie* above, the handler needs to be placed before the loop. You are also missing the `GoTo` statement. You also need an `Exit Sub` statement before the ExitHandler (unless you want to run the `ExitHandler` even if no error occurred - then you leave it away).

I have set up a simplified structure:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long
    
    'Error handler before the loop!
    On Error GoTo ExitHandler
    
    For i = 0 To 12
        'Code to be executed
         Debug.Print 1 / 0

    Next i
    
    MsgBox "No error"
    'Exit sub to avoid that the ExitHandler runs if no error occurs
    'Leve the Exit sub if you want to run the EXitHandler even if no error occurs
    Exit Sub
ExitHandler:
    'Code to perform when an error occurs
    MsgBox "Error occured"
End Sub
```

Be aware that you can also leave the loop in a controlled way using `Exit for`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the next approach, please:

```
Sub testSelectSheet()
   Sheets("Operational").Activate
    For Each pg In Me.MultiPage1.Pages
        x = 1
        For i = 0 To 12
            On Error Resume Next
            'Use True here, to return the check box value:
            If ActiveSheet.Shapes("CheckBox" & x & i).Value = True Then
                'Code to be executed
                 x = x = 1
                 If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0 'clear the error and stopping On Error Resume next effect.
                    'record the error:
                    Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Number & ", Error description: " & Err.Description & " on CheckBox" & x & i
                    'if you want exiting throudh error handler you can use:
                    GoTo ExitHandler
                    ' or if you want exiting, exit directly"
                    Exit Sub
                    'not using any of the above ways to exit, the code will only skip this control and jump to the next one. Only a record in Immediate Window will be made...
                 End If
                 On Error GoTo 0 'make the code stop on error for the next lines
            End If
        Next i
    Next
ExitHandler:
   'no need for Exit Sub, because this is the last procedure row and code exits anyhow...
End Sub
```